# Change settings panel text strings

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, system-settings

[image]

Is there anyway for me to change the text that appears in the menu on the top right? Specifically, I want to change the text that shows up on the battery row (HH:MM Remaining (XX%)). Haven't been able to find where in the system this string is located.

Running Ubuntu 18.04.1.